# Custom Google Maps Style using Google Maps API in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Is there a way to change style of map in iOS using Google Maps SDK?
I know it's possible using Javascript SDK: https://snazzymaps.com/style/6777/new-map

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to style Google Maps for iOS. Google also provides a really nice generator for it:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE (October 2016):**

Recently Google have implemented this feature. @sativa has the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632050/3329130).

**ORIGINAL POST**

Although it's possible on the web, as of now you can't do this through Google Maps SDK for iOS. There's a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4968) that you can join.